# Handler post(Runnable r) with delayed action

Tags: android, push-notification, android-handler, linphone

So, I'm trying to implement a feature that makes my sip phone app wake up and send a registration to the server after receiving a call, which sends a push notification if it is asleep. I'm using the Linphone Library for such means.

This is done trough a method called dispatchOnUIThread(Runnable r), which is suposed to use a handler from its class and post said runnable. The runnable itself implements the actions to be took after receiveing a push and determining if the registration is active or not, as follows:

on the class LinphoneUtils:

```
public final class LinphoneUtils {
private static final Handler sHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

  public static void dispatchOnUIThread(Runnable r) {
      sHandler.post(r);
  }
}
```

and it is called like this:

```
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
  LinphoneUtils.dispatchOnUIThread(mPushReceivedRunnable);
}
```

and the implementation of mPushReceivedRunnable:

```
private Runnable mPushReceivedRunnable =
        new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (!LinphoneContext.isReady()) {
                    new LinphoneContext(getApplicationContext());
                    LinphoneContext.instance().start(true);
                } else {
                    Log.i(TAG, "[Push Notification] Notifying Core");
                    if (LinphoneManager.getLcIfManagerNotDestroyedOrNull() != null && LinphoneManager.getLc().getCallsNb() == 0) {
                        LinphoneCore core = LinphoneManager.getLc();
                        if (core != null) {
                            core.setNetworkReachable(true);
                            core.refreshRegisters();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };
```

The thing is, if the registration is not active, after the dispatchOnUIThread method that follows a push notification, the app does not send a registration to the server until it receives a second push, in which case it sends the registration which was supposed to follow the first push and an invite for the call which sent the second push all together.

The code is pretty similar to the one from Linphone itself, but I don't understend the reason for this delayed action, anyone can tell why it behaves like this?

Answer (score 0):

I guess a later version of the Linphone library fixed the issue.